# django strips out img tag in the text

Tags: python, django, backend

I'm using django to make an online testing system, and I want to render a piece of text from database into the page. The text may have variety numbers of  tag. When the page is rendered, it strips out the  tag and display like this 
      `< img src="{{STATIC_URL}}img/2003/p1q71.jpg" >`
instead of displaying image. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about the built-in [`safe` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#safe).

Django does not consider data from the database to the "Safe".

It always "escapes" any tag-like content in database data to prevent HTML Script Injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

You want to mark the content you are pulling out of the DB as safe when you use it in your template.

```
{{ content_from_db|safe }}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#std:templatefilter-safe